# Why does mailman replace non-Latin letters with crooked ones?

Tags: linux, postfix, encoding, mailman, distribution-lists

The essence of the problem is that when sending an html letter with formatted text inserted from another source containing non-Latin letters (for example, copied text from a web page in Polish), the letter reaches the mailing addressees with corrupted text: instead of non-standard letters (ą , ę, ż, ź), which are not in the English alphabet, codes in the form “С=3” are inserted, which makes the text unreadable. Plus, all the text formatting and tables in this email are falling apart. It turns out to be a mess of English letters, special symbols and numbers. How is this treated and is it treatable at all?

p.s. When sending the same letter directly to one or more recipients, the formatting does not break. The problem only occurs when sending via mailman to mailing lists. The problem does not occur 100% of the time. It all depends on the source from which the formatted text is copied. In all observed cases, it helps to first copy the text into Microsoft Word, and then from it into Thunderbird before sending.

Comment: I'll comment that the problem is that the HTML-formatted letter into which you're inserting the text is not marked as using the UTF-8 charset. When you copy into Word, then paste from there into TBird, Tbird sees that the text is Unicode and includes the charset indicator. There may be a way to tell TBird to  default to UTF-8, which should resolve this, but I'm not an expert at what's available in its settings.

Answer (score 1):

It is not corrupted nor crooked, but *Quoted-Printable Content-Transfer-Encoding* ([RFC 2045, 6.7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2045#section-6.7)).

> The Quoted-Printable encoding is intended to represent data that
> largely consists of octets that correspond to printable characters in
> the US-ASCII character set.  It encodes the data in such a way that
> the resulting octets are unlikely to be modified by mail transport.
> If the data being encoded are mostly US-ASCII text, the encoded form
> of the data remains largely recognizable by humans.

The form is not `C=3` but the sequences start with `=` followed by two hexadecimal characters. E.g., unicode  `U+1F913` *nerd face* is `f0 9f a4 93` in UTF-8 and becomes `=F0=9F=A4=93` in Quoted-Printable.